# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Private.ServiceModel' in Azure Function v2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azureportal, azure-durable-functions

I used a v2 azure function (durable function) with custom dll (.net core 2.2) that calls a service and I get the following exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Private.ServiceModel,
>   Version=4.1.2.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

In the debugging process, I can't step into the method and the exception is thrown without letting me inside it and I don't know exactly what tried to access that library.
Putting manually the package from .nuget in the bin folder didn't work and the strange thing is that if a run the same code with a sample C# function it works.

Answer (score 9):

fixed 
Nuget Install or Update System.Private.ServiceModel

**Install-Package System.Private.ServiceModel -Version 4.7.0**

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Private.ServiceModel/

Comment: I had a project runnitn on IIS using asp.net core 3.1. When website was published i got this error and fixed by installing it.

Answer (score 6):

This issue is detailed here: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2824

How I solved it was to download the nuget `System.Private.ServiceModel`

and add the following to my .csproj

```
<Target Name="CopySPSM" BeforeTargets="Build">
<Copy SourceFiles="$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\system.private.servicemodel\4.5.3\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Private.ServiceModel.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\bin" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this with a Blazor 3.1 app. Works fine locally, but, when deployed to Azure I get:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Private.ServiceModel

To fix it, in the Publish Profile, in Visual Studio, I changed the Target runtime from win-x86 to portable

[image]

Comment: Same here for a .Net5 Asp.Net web app

Answer (score 1):

There is a big thread about this [on github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3568). I added the PostBuild event as in that thread, but I was still struggling in the CI/CD build pipeline.  In the end, I also added a cmd line script step in the build pipeline after the "Build Solution" step with the following code:

```
copy $(Agent.TempDirectory)\WebAppContent\bin\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Private.ServiceModel.dll $(Agent.TempDirectory)\WebAppContent\bin\System.Private.ServiceModel.dll
```

This solution does not seem that clean but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check in your cs.proj if System.Private.ServiceModel.dll is implemanted, if it's not the case you can refer to this work around : https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2824

Comment: If I do that I get : {"net_http_client_execution_error"} System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException